# Footer width 100% stops at 1300px

Tags: css

I'm having some cascading style issues [here](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona)

1) when *height* of screen is smaller than *680px* and *width* more than *1300px*, **footer** (.footer) should be positioned on the very bottom of the page (that works), but it should have **width 100%** (the white strap with copyright in center), but it's not and I can't find out why :(

Could anybody give me hint how to fix it? Everythings seems to me as set width 100%. Issue in every browser. Thanks a lot in advance

My HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix footer">
    <div class="col-12 column">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-margin">
                <div class="navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul id="menu-prvni-menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
                        ...
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="copyright text-center">
                © Copyright 2015 dimension advertising
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
@media (max-height: 680px) {
    .footer {
        position: absolute;
        top: 600px;
        margin: 0 -15px;
    }
}

.copyright.text-center {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.col-12 { width: 100% }
```

Comment: Please include relevant code in your answer, linking to a website is not future proof and it's also impolite to ask others to find their way around your entire CSS codebase.

Comment: I'm sorry, I will do that next time asking here, thanks a lot for your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, your `.footer` has a `margin` set to `0 -15px` which pulls it off to the side, and due to the behavior of setting both left and right margin values to negative being unclear I'd avoid using that entirely, and I urge you to remove that rule.

Directly inside `.footer` you have a `.col-12.coloumn` which gets a left and right padding, further offsetting your values. Reset the padding on it using

```
.footer > .col-12.coloumn { padding: 0 }
```

Apply `!important` after the `0` if needed.

Then, set `.navbar-fixed-bottom` and `.footer` to `width: 100%`. Here's your CSS updated:

```
@media (max-height: 680px) {
    .footer {
        position: absolute;
        top: 600px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .footer > .col-12.column { padding: 0 }
    .navbar-fixed-bottom { width: 100% }
}
```